# Get the first input checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm trying to set the first input element in

```
<div class="containerplaatje klein"> 
    <div class=slides>
       <input...
```

"checked" and remove the "checked" status from all others.
The catch is:

Every time i click on a another container it has to set the first input element in that container to "Checked" and release every other.

See fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/qa6not7w/

I thought this one was close, but I still got a failure:

```
$(document).ready(function info(){
$(".klein").click(function(){

 if ($(this).hasClass("containerplaatje")) {


    $(this).removeClass("containerplaatje");
    $(".containerplaatje2").addClass("containerplaatje");
    $(".containerplaatje2").removeClass("containerplaatje2");
    $(this).addClass("containerplaatje2");
    $(":input").attr ('checked', false);

  /*$('input:radio[name=radio-btn][id=img-1]').attr('checked',true);*/

   }
});
```

Comment: IDs are *unique* throughout the *entire* document.  Why not just: `$('#img-1').attr('checked', true);`?

Comment: The ID is actually not that important for that script, i was using the ID's from a example. I need them for going from one to another picture. If it's possible it may be first input element in that container as selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sets the checkedness state of all radios to false, and then the first one to true:

```
$('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false)[0].checked = true;
```

```js
$('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false)[0].checked = true;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" />
<input type="radio" checked />
<input type="radio" />
```

Note the use of `prop` in jQuery and properties in vanilla-js, instead of `attr` in jQuery and `setAttribute` in vanilla-js.

Comment: Good comment, but i wasn't clear enough in my qeustion. I updated it.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me:

```
      $('input[type=radio]').prop('checked', false);
      $(this).find('input[type=radio]').filter(':first').prop('checked', true);
```